# How to whitelist/allow mobile app generated traffic (API calling) to EC2 API server

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-security-group

I have created API server and website on AWS EC2. I have whitelisted website EC2 IP in API EC2 Security Group, so that it does not get called from anywhere else.
I am developing mobile app in Unity which has to call API. Now, I am not sure how to allow API calls from Mobile App.
Please help.

Comment: You have to allow incoming connections on ports 80 and 443 from the internet (you can't know in advance the IP of the users of your mobile application) in the security group associated to your API instance.

If you don't want your API server to be open on the internet, you can look at the application load balancer which will allow you to expose only the load balancer on the internet.

Have you considered using the Elastic Beanstalk service that could handle all this for you?

Comment: @JulienCsj API server port 80 & 443 is not to be opened for all. I have to do something like allow x.x.x.x on 80/443, instead of allowing 0.0.0.0 on port 80/443

Comment: When users make requests to your API via your application, you cannot know their IP addresses.
In my opinion, if you don't want to redesign the network architecture of your solution, you have no choice but to allow all incoming traffic on your API.
The solution to your problem would be to put your API instance in a private network. This way, by exposing only one load balancer, you can control who can access your API.

Comment: @JulienCsj With ALB exposed to public, again anyone call the API, right?